# AWS security group: Port range?

Tags: amazon-web-services

While configuring security groups in AWS, few parameters are to be selected, like

> Type, Protocol, Port range, Source

What exactly Port range mean? Does it represent port where client process runs or port of the AWS resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does it represent port where client process runs or port of the AWS resource?

It represents ingress or egress ports (e.g. `22-80`) that are allowed through or out of your SG. Your application nor instance may not use these ports at all.

The example range `22-80` for ingress would mean that incoming traffic on ports from 22 to 80 is allowed to pass through the SG. Your instance may not not listen to these ports at all. From SG perspective it does not matter.

Obviously its a bad security practice to open more ingress ports that your instance actually uses. So if you only want to access your instance through port 22 (ssh) and 80 (http), then only allow these to particular ports, not entire range.

Comment: Ok, so does it mean a SG is also a resource and runs on some port. And if its say 80, then I cant have my application, like spring boot application, be on port 80.

Comment: @Mandroid SGs are not user-end application and they don't "run" on any port. The simplest way you can think of them is like instance-level firewalls. They only allow or deny incoming and out coming traffic to and from your instance.